# I want to position two forms right next to each other in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, positioning

I have one form which opens another form.

What I want to do is position the newly opened form right next (on the right side) to the already visible form.

So I need to position the new form to where the current form ends (correct me if wrong).

So I will need to do something like:

```
newform.Left = this.endposition.right;
```

The endposition property is something I just made up (pseudo code).

How to get the end position on the right side of the current form?

**EDIT**

I've tried several solutions but until now none of them worked.

I always get the same result:

[image: Why does this happen]

I've tried the following codes:

```
newform.Left = this.Right + SystemInformation.BorderSize.Width;

newform.Left = this.Right + (SystemInformation.BorderSize.Width * 2);

newform.SetDesktopLocation(this.Location.X + this.Size.Width, this.Location.Y);
```

Eclyps19 suggested to just manually add some pixels to position the new form, although I'm not sure whether the border will be the same on every system.

Answer (score 10):

This works for me:

```
        Form1 nForm = new Form1();
        nForm.Show();
        nForm.SetDesktopLocation(this.Location.X + this.Size.Width, this.Location.Y);
```

Comment: did not work, Isnt there any other settings that I have to toggle?

Comment: I fixed my issue by calling 
"            int _left = this.Parent.Location.X + this.Parent.Size.Width;
            int _top = this.Parent.Location.Y;"

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
newform.Left = oldform.Right + SystemInformation.BorderSize.Width;
```

This should add the width (in pixels) of the border to the oldform.Right value. You can replace (or add to) SystemInformation.BorderSize.Width with any integer you'd like to fit your liking.

Comment: @Eclypse19: Ok getting close: however it doesn't take into account the border of the form.

Comment: You can always add an additional value to it - try newform.left = oldform.right + oldform.BorderSize

Comment: @Eclypse19: `.Right` = same problem. And there is no `.BorderSize` property.

Comment: Woops - disregard my last comment. Try adding SystemInformation.Bordersize to the oldform.Right. This will pull the system's border size value in pixels and add it to the .Right value.

Comment: @Eclypse19: It still overlapses a tiny bit when I use: `newform.Left = this.Right + SystemInformation.BorderSize.Width;` I also tried: `preview.Left = this.Right + (SystemInformation.BorderSize.Width * 2);` which also doesn't work :(

Comment: If you need to make slight adjustments, just increase the extra pixels being added to it with a +1 or +2 or +3 etc.

Comment: @Eclypse19: I thought about it. However I am worried that the difference would be different from system to system. If you are sure that will not be the case I will go down that route.

Comment: Try SizingBorderWidth instead of BorderSize.

Comment: The system-to-system changes will be carried over with the SystemInformation.BorderSize.Width. It sounds like the additional adjustment is strictly your own preference, and SHOULD match from system to system. Are you sure the slight overlap is not due to one being selected (and thus possibly having a deeper border)?

Answer (score 1):

I Know this question is old, but for anyone coming here looking for an answer, you need to take into account the size of both form's borders. The border size will be different depending on the `FormBorderStyle`.

```
var newForm = new Form2();
newForm.Show();
var form1Border = (this.Width - this.ClientSize.Width) / 2;
var newFormBorder = (newForm.Width - newForm.ClientSize.Width) / 2;
newForm.Left = this.Left + this.Width - form1Border - newFormBorder;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, but you just have to put it AFTER your newForm.Show() method.